# Paging file and swap partition on a Ubuntu/Windows 7 dual boot

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning, swap, paging

I'm planning hard drive partitions for my new laptop and I had a curious idea:

**Can the same partition be used to house both the paging file (windows) and the swap space (linux)?**

The reasoning behind the question is that both the paging file and swap space are only used while the corresponding OS is active (or hibernating, but I dont think I can boot one while the other is in hibernation), so I should be able to use the same partition to perform those tasks, right?

It probably cannot be done due to file system incompatibility but I think is worth asking.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do this.  Typically, Linux dedicates a disk partition to swap.  Windows creates a file on the boot drive, by default, for the page file.  While you can move this file to another location, Windows cant read a Linux swap partition.  Therefore you couldnt have the two coexist.